# Unable to add guest users to M365 group after setting AllowAddGuests policy to True

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created a group in my demo tenant with the following settings:

[image]

My application is set as the owner of this group. When I try to add guest users programmatically, I see the following error:

```
Response - StatusCode:Forbidden - Content:{
"error": {
"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
"message": "Guests users are not allowed to join this Unified Group due to policy setting. paramName: Members, paramValue: , objectType: Microsoft.Online.DirectoryServices.Group",
}
}
```

However, when I manually add as an owner of the group via Azure Portal, I can add successfully.

What am I missing?

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/solutions/per-group-guest-access?view=o365-worldwide

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Application** like below:

[image]

Now, I added the **Service Principal as the owner of the unified group** like below:

[image]

Checked the unified group settings:

```
Get-UnifiedGroup testrukk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com | fl *Allow*
```

[image]

I generated **access token** using the below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, **no roles/scopes are displayed**:

[image]

Now, when I tried to add the guest user as the member of the group, I got the below error:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupObjID/members/$ref

{
"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/GuestUserObjID"
}
```

[image]

To error ***"Authorization_RequestDenied"*** usually occurs if the access token you are passing doesn't contain required roles to perform the action.

**To resolve the error**, make sure to add **`GroupMember.ReadWrite.All`** permission like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token when decoded role is displayed**:

[image]

***I am able to successfully add the guest user as the member of the group:***

[image]

[image]

> **Note** that: Even if the Service Principal is the owner of the group, the access token must include required roles to perform the action. Graph API permissions is required to execute the Graph queries.

**Reference:**

[Add members - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)